# Changing time base on an ffmpeg encode (libffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using libffmpeg to decode an RTSP video stream and write it to a file.

The time_base reported by the codec when I open the stream is 1 / 180000. When I create my output AVStream, I'm copying this time_base over to the output. It works, but I get this message when I call avformat_write_header:

"WARNING codec timebase is very high. If duration is too long,file may not be playable by quicktime. Specify a shorter timebase"

I tried specifying a shorter timebase (say, 1/30) but when I do this, the video plays back at the wrong speed.

What's the right way to adjust the time_base on my output stream without modifying the playback time?

Thanks.

Comment: Not fluent with FFmpeg API use, but have you [rescaled](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c#L81) the PTS after changing the time base?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that and tried it... results were odd. It did change the playback rate, but not by the amount I thought.

Comment: Sounds like that's the right approach but you had the wrong calibration.

Comment: For example, if I change the time base on the output stream to 1/30 instead of 1/180000, that should be a factor of 6000. But if I multiply pts and dts by 6000, the video plays way too fast.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?